# Convertin Cartesian to Polar in bash

Tags: linux, bash, math, bc

We got homework to convert Cartesian Coordinates to Polar Coordinates and I don't even know how to start. So any little help would be nice.

We have to write code in bash. Here is the example that we got:

```
script.sh 256 128
Result: 286.216 1.107
```

We have to insert number as parameters and we have to use bc interpreter.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/bc

Comment: If your difficulty is understanding how to convert from Cartesian to polar co-ordinates you could try the web page [Polar and Cartesian Co-ordinates](http://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html). If your difficulty is how to do that in `bc`, or how to capture parameters to a `bash` script and feed them into `bc`, you could try an example (look at some of the related questions and answers shown to the right of this page) then you could revise your question to show your specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's your homework, i wrote your program but i put hook into it.My task has some advantages for you:

1. you can hack bash.
2. you can hack awk.
3. you can prevent of math in bash
4. you can prevent Radian/Degree expression

I only example for call function, unless i complete my program, you see at end of my prog, some call func, it's not my entire main.write a main for it.

My program:

```
#!/bin/bash

### X and Y 
export x=$1
export y=$2

####calculating r:

export r=`echo "sqrt(x*x+y*y)" |bc -l ` 


####Radian to Degree
r2d(){
    echo "180,3.14156265358979323846,`echo  $1`" |awk ' BEGIN {FS=","} { print $1/$2*$3'} ###HOOK

}
####Degree to Radian
d2r(){

    echo "180,3.14156265358979323846,`echo  $1`" |awk ' BEGIN {FS=","} { print $2/$1*$3'} ###HOOK
}

teta(){
    if [ $x -lt 0 ];then 

        echo `echo "$1,$2" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} {print 3.14156265358979323846+atan2($2/$1,1)'}`  ####HOOK
    fi;

    if [ $x  -gt 0 ];then 
        echo `echo "$1,$2" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} {print atan2($2/$1,1)'}`  ####HOOK
    fi;
}

echo `r2d 2.09`
echo `d2r 120`
echo `teta $x,$y`
```

Comment: Why do you export `x`, `y`, and `r`?

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

- use the `-l` option to bc
- you'll need the `sqrt()` and `a()` functions
- be clear about which value is "x" and which is "y"
- use `scale=3` to limit the precision
- `bc` reads its program from stdin